# What do the leaf numbers represent in the h2o tree plot?

Tags: python, classification, h2o, xgboost, gbm

[image: Tree plotted]

My classification is a 0-1 classification.So what exactly are the numbers at the bottom telling me [ why are they negative and all] ? Also what do the NAs mean? Do they say that this particular feature is not classified on a numeric comparison hence NA like BreedName?

Here are the columns of my data and 'L' is the 0-1 column i.e my y.
[image: Data]

Ques2- This tree 0 is the main model right since i have done cv(n=3) and i have got 4 trees [0,1,2,3] and whatever i interpret should be based on the 0th tree right?

Answer (score 0):

The [NA]s displayed close to node links mean that all nan values will go through this link.

I am not sure how h2o trees handle nan target values. Anyway, it is never a good idea to keep them. You should try to remove them or to replace them with 0 and 1 according to your problem.

The "number at the bottom" of your tree seem weird... Why is there written "class 0" at the top of your tree ? Are you training class 0 and class 1 separately ? Could you clarify how do you proceed your tree(s) training ?

I am not sure what you mean by "I have 4 trees". Cross validation is only used to check how good you model can predict your data. But the model you will use to predict your future data is not the one you used to cross validate. It has to be a different model fitted with all your current data.

Comment: Check the link that i posted to understand more

Comment: Also i read somewhere that the leaf node values for binary classification in xgboost [scikit learn] gives the value of x for p[x=1]=sigmoid(x)..is it the same here for h2o as well

Answer (score 0):

Answering inline since there are a few questions:

*My classification is a 0-1 classification.So what exactly are the numbers at the bottom telling me [ why are they negative and all] ?*

You are showing an image of Tree 0, this is the first tree that is built (so not your main model). The tree leaf values are the corrections, you should use `h2o.predict()` to see what your final model's predictions are.

*Also what do the NAs mean?*

The `[NA]` refers to NAs in your dataset. The ones you see along the tree splits just specify which way an NA should go.

*This tree 0 is the main model right since i have done cv(n=3) and i have got 4 trees [0,1,2,3] and whatever i interpret should be based on the 0th tree right?*

Tree 0 is the first tree built not your final model. Please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cross-validation.html) on cross-validation for a detailed explanation on the model building process for CV

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the underlying code that calculates the prediction from the tree here for GBM:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/bddb258e612994c3b53fc7c73d24bf88b6b211ab/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/algos/gbm/GbmMojoModel.java#L54